# what is the space complexity of a list inside for loop?

Tags: java, algorithm

When creating new `List` inside `For` loop with the same name. Is it mean that compute space complexity one time or compute it with every loop. let say:

```
for (int u = 0; u < 5; u++) {

                List<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                fileNameList.add(concatinateFileWithTf);
  }
```

from the previous example i created `fileNameList` with every loop but with the same name. Is it mean that i create new list and should compute its space complexity each time or it make restore for this list?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it mean that i create new list and should compute its space complexity each time

Yes.

From javadoc of `new ArrayList<>();`:

> Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

So, each iteration you allocate memory for list with size 1 and capacity 10.

Ask if smth still unclear.

Comment: Actually, since Java 8 empty ArrayList instances reuse static `Object[0]` array, reducing memory footprint. @shsa, take a look at lines 156 and 195 [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java), it may help you.

Comment: @Woland, if it creates new List with every loop, what happened with the previous List generated from the previous loop?Is it erased from memory or allocate more than one List with the same name?please can you clarify that to me?

Comment: @shsa "previous List" lives in heap until GC will collect and remove him from memory. Depends on GC algorithm. JVM internally track objects not by their's name. I don't know exactly, but can suppose it uses hashcode or smth similar.

Comment: @shsa you can start from this link https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm6.html :)

Comment: @Woland, it mean that if i store value in variables declared in for loop, it create this variables each time. let say: 'for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { double g = ra.nextFloat(); double n = (double) ((double) Math.round(g * 10) / 10.0); }' i understood that the previous code make restore to variables with new values and not occupy new places in memory.